# How can I Solve the problem of multi period EOQ

Tags: python, pyomo

Hi guys I am trying to solve multi period EOQ model. I define the disocunt constraint with buring_price. So that  if the Q was upper then a limit, the price would change and I faced this error form the rule section line 56.

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

# Time periods
model.T = pyo.RangeSet(4)

# Parameters during period t
model.D = {1: 15 , 2: 5 , 3: 20 , 4: 40}        # D = Demand
model.C = {1: 20 , 2: 20 , 3: 20 , 4: 20}       # C = Ordering Cost
model.H = {1: 2 , 2: 2 , 3: 2 , 4:2}            # H = Holding Costs


# Variables during period t
model.B = pyo.Var( domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)             # B = buring price
model.Q = pyo.Var(model.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)     # Q = Quantity
model.I = pyo.Var(model.T, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)     # I = Inventory
I0 = 0                                                      # I0 = Inventory in the first round
Q_List = []                                                 # Q_List = Put the Q value in the list

# Simplifying parameters
T = model.T
Q = model.Q
I = model.I
D = model.D
C = model.C
H = model.H
B = model.B

# Define the inventory relationships
def inventory_Online (m,t) :
    if t == m.T.first() :
        return m.I[t] == (I0 + m.Q[t]) - m.D[t]
    return model.I[t] == (m.I[t-1] + m.Q[t]) - m.D[t]
model.inventory = pyo.Constraint(model.T, rule = inventory_Online)

# Define the cost function
def Obj_rule(m,t) :
    TIC = sum(m.C[t]*m.D[t]/m.Q[t] + m.H[t]*m.I[t] + m.H[t]*m.Q[t]/2 + m.B for t in model.T)
    return TIC
model.Obj = pyo.Objective(rule=Obj_rule , sense=minimize)

# Define the buring_price
def buring_price (m,t):
    for t in model.T:
        if m.Q[t] > 0 and m.Q[t] >=10:
            return m.B == m.Q[t]*10

        elif m.Q[t] > 10 and m.Q[t] <= 100:
            return m.B == m.Q[t]*9

        else:
           return m.B == m.Q[t]*8
model.discount = pyo.Constraint(rule= buring_price)

# Solve the problem
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt',executable='C:\\Ipopt\\bin\\ipopt.exe')
opt.solve(model)

# Print the results
model.pprint()
TIC_Optimal = pyo.value(Obj_rule(model,T))

print('-------------------------TIC Optimal----------------------------------')
print('TIC Optimal =',TIC_Optimal)

print('-------------------------I[t]----------------------------------')
for t in model.T:
    print('Period: {0}, Prod. Amount: {1}'.format(t, pyo.value(model.I[t])))

print('-------------------------Q[t]----------------------------------')
for t in model.T:
    print('Period: {0}, Prod. Amount: {1}'.format(t, pyo.value(model.Q[t])))

print('-------------------------Q[t] List----------------------------------')
for t in model.T:
    Q_List.append(pyo.value(model.Q[t]))
print(Q_List)
```

I would be thankful to help me.

## ERROR

ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint discount with
index None: PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant expression to
bool. This error is usually caused by using an expression in a boolean
context such as an if statement. For example,
m.x = Var() if m.x <= 0:
...

Comment: You **cannot** bury an "if" statement in the model construction process that depends on the value of a variable.  The variable value *is not known* when the model is created.  You will have to re-formulate your model in linear terms.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.